# Если поле формы не заполнено менять содержимое письма

Tags: php

Есть форма с необязательными полями. Нужно, если не заполняют эти поля то письмо выводить без "пустых" этих полей.

Я попытался сделать вот так, но видимо какая-то ошибка. Письмо просто перестало приходить.

```
    <?php
        $to = '';
        $firstname = $_POST["name"];
        $email= $_POST["email"];
        $text= $_POST["message"];

        $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: " . $email . "\r\n"; // Sender's E-mail
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

        if (!empty($text)) {
            $message ='<table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td>'.$firstname.'</td>
            </tr>

            <tr><td>Email:<b> '.$email.'</b></td></tr>


         </table>';
        } else {
            $message ='<table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td>'.$firstname.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Email:<b> '.$email.'</b></td></tr>

            <tr><td>Text: '.$text.'</td></tr>
        </table>';
        }


       @mail($to, $email, $message, $headers)
?>
```

Comment: Точнее приходит всегда то что после else.

Comment: Проверьте на существования таких полей вообще функцией **isset()**

Comment: Вот вы не проверяете что вернула функция `mail()`, не смотрите лог ошибок. А скрипт то вообще отработал ?! И после этого спрашиваете что не так ?!